# R extract value from a data frame with different length based on a column

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have 2 data frames.

Data1 is like this (with length of 50)

```
|Depth|Age|
|1|56|
|2|78|
|3|104|
|4|157|
|5|200|
```

Data 2 is like this (with lenght of 300)

```
|Age|Rate|
|1|15.2|
|2|15.4|
|3|15.6|
|4|16.4|
|5|17.8|
|..|..|
|300|19.1|
```

I want to create a new column `Rate` in `Data1` based on `Age`, and the value of `Rate` is from `Data2` with corresponding `Age` (same age in `Data1` and `Data2`).

I want the output to be like this:

```
|Depth|Age|Rate|
|1|56|18.1|
|2|78|20.1|
|3|104|21.0|
|4|157|20.2|
|5|200|23.1|
```

I tried if else and it said cannot work because the data frame's length is different.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by = 'Age', all.x = TRUE)` is what you need

Comment: The merge(df1, df2) worked! I feel dumb, such a simple solution! thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: Be sure to always [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Found it using match:

```
data1$rate <- data2$rate[match(data1$age,data2$age)]
```

I found the solution here
[Add column to data frame based on values of another column in another row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326168/add-column-to-data-frame-based-on-values-of-another-column-in-another-row)